# Unit systemd-resolved.service is masked

Tags: 18.04, server, systemd

I was trying to restart the `systemd-resolved.service` with the command:

```
sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved
```

and got the error message:

```
Failed to restart systemd-resolved.service: Unit systemd-resolved.service is masked.
```

File the `systemd-resolved.service` exists in the folder `/lib/systemd/system`.

The status of the service is:

```
/lib/systemd/system# systemctl status systemd-resolved.service
● systemd-resolved.service
   Loaded: masked (/dev/null; bad)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

When I try to execute with:

```
/lib/systemd/system/systemd-resolved.service
-bash: /lib/systemd/system/systemd-resolved.service: Permission denied
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8):

If your service is masked it is symlinked to /dev/null
You can verify by:

```
ls -l /etc/systemd/system/systemd-resolved.service
```

To remove the mask simply run:

```
sudo systemctl unmask systemd-resolved
```

`/lib/systemd/system/systemd-resolved.service` is a text file and cannot be executed by bash. The service binary is located `/lib/systemd/systemd-resolved`

Answer (score 3):

Try removing the systemd service file and then starting it again.

Remove the file-

```
sudo rm /lib/systemd/system/systemd-resolved.service
```

Reload the daemon

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

Once reloaded, start the service

```
sudo systemctl start systemd-resolved
sudo systemctl enable systemd-resolved
```

Note: For getting the location of systemd-resolved service you can use ***sudo systemctl enable systemd-resolved*** and further use the location for removing the file.

The masked systemd service made my system have issues with network manager and I was not being able to use internet on the system. When I checked further for errors or warnings using ***grep resolved /var/log/syslog*** command, I came across the error that this service is masked and unmasked it using the solution above.

Comment: What is the purpose of deleting the service file?

Comment: @RomanK unmask didn't worked in my case, so I deleted the service first and then restarted it, and that worked! so I shared that here.

Comment: If you will delete that `Unit`, the service cannot start unless you have drop-in in `/etc/systemd/system/` or in other paths as [per documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html). Removing the file is a bad advice.

Comment: @RomanK But that was created by itself when i started the service. I don't have explored it that much, but after grinding for two days, this method worked for me and I shared it. I'll keep your advice in mind, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use this command

```
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to [RomanK](https://askubuntu.com/users/869765/romank)'s answer above, 
use the `unmask` command to unmask any service that is listed in the error, 
for example:

If you get

```
...Unit systemd-networkd.service is masked...
```

then run the command

```
sudo systemctl unmask systemd-networkd.service
```

(see also this [archived answer](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=193036) for ways to list masked services)