# update-motd not updating on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ssh, motd

I'm having trouble getting **any** output when logging in via SSH.

I removed all scripts under `/etc/update-motd.d/` and I installed my own `bash` scripts.

#### Before

```bsh
➜  ~ ls -la /etc/update-motd.d/
total 64
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Apr 19 19:34 .
drwxr-xr-x 106 root root 4096 Apr 24 11:41 ..
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 1220 Dec  5  2019 00-header
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 1157 Dec  5  2019 10-help-text
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root   46 Apr 19 19:34 50-landscape-sysinfo -> /usr/share/landscape/landscape-sysinfo.wrapper
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 5023 Aug 17  2020 50-motd-news
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root   84 Feb 21 03:06 85-fwupd
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  106 Apr 29  2021 88-esm-announce
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  218 May 14  2021 90-updates-available
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  112 Apr 29  2021 91-contract-ua-esm-status
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  374 Apr 14 17:21 91-release-upgrade
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  165 Jul 21  2020 92-unattended-upgrades
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  129 May 14  2021 95-hwe-eol
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  111 Nov  2 14:33 97-overlayroot
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  142 May 14  2021 98-fsck-at-reboot
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  144 May 14  2021 98-reboot-required
```

#### After

```bsh
➜  ~ ls -la /etc/update-motd.d/
total 28
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Apr 24 11:45 .
drwxr-xr-x 106 root root 4096 Apr 24 11:48 ..
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  146 Apr 24 11:45 .common.sh
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  152 Apr 24 11:45 00-daze-banner
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  294 Apr 24 11:45 10-security-warning
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  414 Apr 24 11:45 50-ubuntu-flavour
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 1313 Apr 24 11:45 90-sys-info
```

This is what is in my `/etc/pam.d/{login,sshd}` files:

```bsh
➜  ~ grep "motd" /etc/pam.d/login
session    optional   pam_motd.so motd=/run/motd.dynamic.new
#session    optional   pam_motd.so noupdate
```

```bsh
➜  ~ grep "motd" /etc/pam.d/sshd 
session    optional     pam_motd.so  motd=/run/motd.dynamic.new
#session    optional     pam_motd.so noupdate
```

And in my `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file I have the `PrintMotd Yes` option.

I think the problem is that the `/run/motd.dynamic.new` file never gets updated and is always empty:

```bsh
➜  ~ wc /run/motd.dynamic.new
0 0 0 /run/motd.dynamic.new
```

Running `sudo run-parts /etc/update-motd.d/` produces the expected output.

- Can you tell me what's wrong?
- How can I debug it?

#### Note

In the scripts I'm using some utilities like `lolcat`, `boxes` and `figlet` to make text look like this:

[ssh login expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cH7rQ.png)

Comment: You can run this command to see if there are any errors in the scripts: `sudo run-parts /etc/update-motd.d/`.

Comment: I already ran that command as I specified in the question and the output is what you see in the image attached.

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 and have a custom script in there, but `/run/motd.dynamic.new` doesn't exist.

Comment: @kungfubamba this question helped me to see the problem: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1207493/unit-systemd-resolved-service-is-masked

Comment: MacMartin perhaps you'd like to submit an answer to the motd question with the insight gained from the related linked answer.